# How can I aggregate several states into one master state with react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize if I didn't phrase the question correctly so let me explain.

I have a reusable Filter component that generates checkboxes or radio buttons depending on a predetermined list.

For example, the lists below will generate each a Filter component with that many checkboxes and labels

```
const genre = ["Action", "Horror", "Comedy", "Drama"];
const contenttype = ["Series", "Movies", "Documentaries"];
const dategranularity = ["All Time", "Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly"];
```

like so

```
<Filter data={genre} label="Genre" checkboxgroup />
<Filter data={contenttype} label="Content Type" checkboxgroup />
<Filter data={dategranularity} label="Date Granularity" defaultValue="all time" />
```

Here's the Filter component function I am using for my goal (reduced for brevity)

```
const Filter = ({ data, label, checkboxgroup, defaultValue }) => {

  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState([]);
  const [radios, setRadios] = useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  const handleList = (e) => {
    const updatedValuesState = values.includes(e.target.name)
      ? values.filter((label) => label !== e.target.name)
      : [...values, e.target.name];
    setValues(updatedValuesState);
    setActive(updatedValuesState.length === data.length);
  };
};
```

At the moment I able to capture and aggregate the checkboxes that are checked ONLY within its own Filter component So for example if I clicked on action and horror, I get `values:  ['action', 'horror']` in my console. That's good! But if I click on "series" on the next Filter component, the state is completely rebuilt and it console logs `values:  ['series']`.

My end goal is to show `values:  ['action', 'horror', 'series']` even the radio button value can be aggregated but only once. as opposed to checkboxes can be multiple.

Here's a [**sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ramanujan-uhoyrf) with all you need in place to mess with it. Thanks!!!

Comment: This sounds like an architecture problem: your filter component should probably emit its selected filters to the parent component, which will then collect all filters from each of its child `<Filter>` component so that it has a master list of filters.

Comment: @Terry That's how I thought I'd handle it. I think with callback. But I was getting some inconsistent data passed, a mixed of truths and undefined. The answer below sort of works except the radio button doesn't register ONLY the one selected. Instead is aggregating as the checkboxes do. Only the checkboxes can have multiple values. With the radios it should be only the last one selected. Also the setFilterState(Array.from()) is breaking the material checkbox. An alternate answer would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each instance of the Filter component is an isolated instance, and each of them with has an isolated state (the states don't interact with each other). In this case the quickest solution, by following your code would be to do something like this:

```js
const genre = ["Action", "Horror", "Comedy", "Drama"];
const contenttype = ["Series", "Movies", "Documentaries"];
const dategranularity = ["All Time", "Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly"];

const Filter = ({ data, values, onChange, label, checkboxgroup, defaultValue }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleSwitch = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setActive(true);
      onChange(data.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()));
    } else {
      setActive(false);
      onChange([]);
    }
  };

  // new unique Filter's onChange 
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    let newValue = [];

    if (checkboxgroup) {
      const value = e.target.name;
      newValue = values.includes(value)
        ? values.filter((label) => label !== value)
        : [...values, value];
    } else {
      const value = e.target.value;
      newValue = [value];
    }

    onChange(newValue);
    setActive(newValue.length === data.length);
  };
};

const Form = () => {
  const [_genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const [_contentType, setContentType] = useState([]);
  const [_dateGranularity, setDateGranularity] = useState([]);

  const handleAdvDrawerClose = () => {
    const results = [..._genres, ..._contentType, ..._dateGranularity];

    console.log("genres", _genres);
    console.log("contentType", _contentType);
    console.log("dateGranularity", _dateGranularity);
    console.log("results", results);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Filter
        data={genre}
        values={_genres}
        onChange={setGenres}
        label="Genre"
        checkboxgroup
      />
      <Filter
        data={contenttype}
        values={_contentType}
        onChange={setContentType}
        label="Content Type"
        checkboxgroup
      />
      <Filter
        data={dategranularity}
        values={_dateGranularity}
        onChange={setDateGranularity}
        label="Date Granularity"
        defaultValue="all time"
      />
      <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={handleAdvDrawerClose}>
        Show Results
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the link for the fork [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-fast-y5fwwd?file=/src/App.js)
But basically what I did was simplify the onChange of the Filter, and the component now has 2 new props, the `values` and `onChange`, where the values is the selected values of the Filter and onChange is the onChange of the main component's state. And in the end where you click "Show Results" I merge all the states

Comment: Genius! Obrigado pela resposta mano! Abraços do Brasil

Answer (score 4):

Every Filter component declared is its own instance. So genre and contenttype filter components won't be aware of each other.

However, we can declare a parent state which can be passed to all the filter components, although it will end up polluting the common Filter component.

I tried to do it, you can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-darkness-6bz69o?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: This is pretty good! IS tehre anyway that the radio values can only aggregate once? Basically only the active radio button gets added. Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, you can. Before adding the currently selected radio value in the filterState, remove all radioValues from the filter state, then add the latest selected value.

Comment: Could you take a loo at the codesandbox. I think I did what you said but it's not working